# How can I return an id value from a div already populated through ajax

Tags: ajax, variables, loops, html

I am having some difficulty passing a correct id function back to AJAX.
I'm creating a product bulletin generator that lets items to be added by their SKU code (which works fine). My problem is that when a bulletin is clicked on, a preview of that bulletin is loaded into a div and shows all products associated with that bulletin.
 From inside those results, I am trying to add the ability to delete a product from the bulletin.  The problem is that the value being passed back to AJAX belongs to the first product only.  It won't send the value belonging to the particular item if it is any other item than the first one.

This is the code (belonging to main.php) that gets loaded via AJAX into a div and is looped with each product associated with a selected bulletin

```
    echo "<form name='myDelForm'>
    $news_gen_id<br>
    <input type='hidden' id='delccode' value='".$news_gen_id."'>
    <input type='hidden'     id='deledit' value='".$edit."'>
    <input type='button' onclick='ajaxDelCcode()' value='Delete' /><br></form>
    </td>";
```

The AJAX code (on index.php, where the div that calls in main.php is also located) is this

```
function ajaxDelCcode(){
    var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!
try{
    // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch (e){
    // Internet Explorer Browsers
    try{
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new 
ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e){
            // Something went wrong
            alert("Your browser broke!");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
// Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
        var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById("ajaxMain2");
        ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
    }
}
var deledit = document.getElementById("deledit").value;
var delccode = document.getElementById("delccode").value;
var queryString = "?delccode=" + delccode + "&deledit=" + deledit;
ajaxRequest.open("GET", "main.php" + queryString, true);
ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}
//-->
</script>
```

Currently, using those two pieces of code, I can successfully delete only the first product.  The delccode variables do not seem to change when the products are looped (although when I echo the variables during the loop, it is definitely changing to the appropriate value...it's just not passing it correctly back to AJAX.)

I tried taking the AJAX code, putting it inside the main.php product loop, and change the function name during each loop  (so ajaxDelCcode$news_gen_id()  for example) and also to the button itself so that it is calling the AJAX specific to it. And it works if you are visiting main.php directly...but not from index.php after main.php has been called into the div.

I can't figure out how to pass the correct looped value from main.php within the div, back to the AJAX code on index.php

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks,

Dustin

Comment: For anyone using ajax, I HIGHLY suggest using jQuery. It does ajax with much less manual coding and is much more compatible between browsers. http://jquery.com/ and  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/. So much so, in fact, I can't believe people still do it this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of storing the id in the input, just pass it as an argument to the function:

```
function ajaxDelCcode(delccode) { ...

<input type='button' onclick='ajaxDelCcode(\"".$news_gen_id."\")' value='Delete' />
```

Also, I'd swap the quotes if I were you. Or better yet, instead of using echo, break the PHP code and just write HTML:

```
<? ... ?><input type="button" onclick="ajaxDelCcode('<?= $news_gen_id ?>')" value="Delete" /><? ... ?>
```

Comment: YES!!! Almost there!! I switched it to your 2nd suggestion (breaking the PHP code with HTML between) and had a bit of trouble until I realized the var delccode = document.getElementById("delccode").value; was interfering in the function.    I deleted it, but had a bit of code conflict (with another part of the generator) because I need to bring both the delccode variable and the deledit variable.   If I hardcode the deledit id into the script instead of a variable, then everything works fine.   So my last question is, can I pass both the delccode and deledit variables using this approach?

Comment: MWAHAHAHAHA!!!! Duplicated the approach ajaxDelCcode(delccode,deledit)  and everytthing works smooooooooooooothly and sweetly.  I am going to revisit the rest of the generator to clean up the code and switch over to this approach.   Thank you so much!  This is perfect

Comment: While we're at it,  $query = "DELETE FROM news_gen WHERE news_gen_id='$delccode'"; -- be sure to sanitize $delcode with mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: Will do. Thanks again a sad dude.  :)

Answer (score 0):

What does the code you use to delete look like? Is it in the same php file as the form you posted above? If so, is the form getting submitted to itself accidentally? Like perhaps when a user presses enter while on an input type=text control? I understand that you want to do this by ajax but I am suspecting that the form is your problem.

Seconding the jQuery comment.

Comment: Near the top of main.php  I have the GET statement to grab the delccode and deledit vars.... then I simply have       if($delccode!=''){
    //echo "$delccode would be deleted";
    $query = "DELETE FROM news_gen WHERE     news_gen_id='$delccode'"; 
    mysql_query($query); 
    $delccode='';
     }

Comment: You should probably escape any user input in your sql statements.

As well, is that from the same php file as the one above? Does $delccode have a default value?

Comment: The above section is in two files.  ajax function is in index.php and the button calling the function is in main.php (which is loaded into a div only after a bulletin has been chosen)...the delete code is in the main.php shortly after it checks for a variable to delete and a variable specifying which issue (deledit) it is deleting from.  $delccode doesn't have a default value.

Comment: I will explore more about jquery as time permits.  I only get so much researching time at work :(

Answer (score 0):

Here try this

1) add jquery to your document.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

2) give your inputs name attributes

```
<input type='hidden' name='delcode' id='delccode' value='".$news_gen_id."'>
<input type='hidden' name='deledit' id='deledit' value='".$edit."'>
```

3) Use a function something like this instead of all that code above

```
function ajaxDelCcode() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "main.php",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "text",
    data: $("#myDelForm").serialize(),
    success: function(rText) {
      $("#ajaxMain2").text(rText);
    }
  });
}
```